# Place map above another view Swift UI

Tags: swiftui

I want the map to be above the bottom-slider always Whenever the bottom-slider move up the map go with it and adjust always stay above it.

This is my code, Btw I started a swift today

```
 var body: some View {
ZStack(alignment: Alignment.top) {
        MapView()
     // From here I want the MapView which is google maps above the SlideOverCard
        SlideOverCard {
            VStack {
                Text("Whatever")
                    .font(.headline)
                
            }.frame(width: 1000)
        }
    }
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.vertical)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give either `.zIndex` or change the order of views in `ZStack`(the latest will be the top-most)

A)

```
ZStack(alignment: Alignment.top) {
        MapView().zIndex(1)         // by default all views has 0
        SlideOverCard {
```

B)

```
ZStack(alignment: Alignment.top) {
        SlideOverCard {
            // ... other code here
        }
        MapView()      // will be above
}
```

Comment: Thank you that's simple! but also it's not auto-adjusting to the slider doesn't go up anymore when I slide it up, it goes behind the map

Comment: Not sure I understood you, but you can change zIndex conditionally, so view dynamically go above or below some other view.

Comment: I just started SWIFT today literally basics
In android, we can just say example stay above this other layout but here as you show me I can put above but it's not changing with the other view so it makes it behind it,
SlideOverCard is A bottom sheet slider who slide up whenever you swipe up it get bigger and more up , What I want is when I swipe it up automatically maps go more up with it as if its sticking to the bottom slider

Comment: That sounds as you need VStack instead of ZStack.

Comment: I will try it now

Comment: No luck the map vanished and the slide got duplicated 3 times above each other can slide between them weird behavior

Comment: I edited SlideOverCard{}.zIndex(1) all perfect! Thank you so much, bro, please edit the answer, If you like